# appending <option> in select tag on click function of jquery not working properly

Tags: jquery, html, drop-down-menu

Dropdown gets populated but when i click on the select tag for the first time it does't show all the list, but shows button to scroll through list and on second click, it shows complete list. i am attaching images of first click and second click behavior and code example.

[first and second click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eMb8h.jpg)

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/38195.png)

Comment: Can you post the relevant snippet of code?

Comment: Posting an image in OP will not help SO people determine the problem post some code in OP or demo using `<>`

Comment: See how to create a [mcve]

Comment: If the `<select>` is populated via AJAX, then it may just be taking time for it to load. Adding some wait time for it to be ready might help. As was already commented, we need to see an example of your code. Please review: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Yes i am adding data using ajax, can you please tell me how to add delay?

Comment: @RaymondChavez i have added code snipped, please check now.

Comment: @ShaurBinTalib you should follow the guidelines in the links above with regard to an MCVE.  In particular, "if a web page problem requires HTML, some JavaScript and a stylesheet, include all three."  For your question, we'd need to see the relevant HTML.  Lastly, use `code` markdown in your question instead of linking to screenshots.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since you have provided almost no proper example, it is hard to how your HTML is setup of if you're using any frameworks like jQuery UI.

Basically, you will want to use `.preventDefault()` and then `return true` combination to ensure the AJAX has completed before showing the `<options>`. This example does not mimic an AJAX call, but does take time to build the menu.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/nn4m0c6r/

**HTML**

```
<div>
  <label for="pro_id">Select Product</label>
  <select name="pro_id" id="pro_id">
    <option>Select Product</option>
  </select>
  <button>Search</button>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
  var i = 0,
    r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000),
    opts = [];
  for (i; i <= r; i++) {
    opts.push({
      id: i,
      name: "Product Name " + i
    });
  }
  $("#pro_id").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      url: "/echo/json/",
      dataType: "JSON",
      data: {
        json: JSON.stringify(opts)
      },
      type: "POST",
      success: function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(index, row) {
          $("#pro_id").append("<option value='" + row.id + "'>" + row.name + "</option>");
        });
      }
    });
    return true;
  });
});
```

You didn't specify if you were receiving JSON data, but based on your code, it looks that way. Better to use `$.ajax()` in my opinion. The select will open while the AJAX is retrieving data and then the options show up. So there will be some lag. If possible, it would be best to gather that data while the page is rendering or just after `ready`.

Comment: Also you can save yourself some time by creating the eclipse in CSS versus your in Script.